# Mongoose doesn't create model object with array

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm working on a project where I have the following mongoose schema:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Env', {
    name : {type : String, default: ''},
    services: [ServiceAddress]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('ServiceAddress', {
    serviceId : {type : ObjectId},
    address: {type: String}
});
```

I'm trying to update an existing 'Env' document which has an empty array of 'services'.

```
router.put('/api/env', function(req, res, next) {
    var env = new Environment(req.body);
    env.save(function(err, updated){
        if (err){
            res.send(err);
        }
        res.json(updated);
    });
});
```

The req.body content is:

```
{
   _id: "56dd26a6618c1b983d5bada6", 
   name: "Test Drive"
   services: [{_id: "56dc6e385fb0b038241d3399", address: "11"}, {_id:     "56dc6e595fb0b038241d339a", address: ""}]
}
```

But the result in the DB is (only the IDs are pushed):

```
"services" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("56dc6e385fb0b038241d3399") }, { "_id" : ObjectId("56dc6e595fb0b038241d339a") }
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try out with following snippet

```
var serviceSchema = {
    serviceId : {type : ObjectId,required: false},
    address: {type: String,required: false}
};
// added so that new _id field is not added when object is pushed in array
serviceSchema  = 'new Schema('+serviceSchema +',{_id:false})';

module.exports = mongoose.model('Env', {
    name : {type : String, default: ''},
    services: [serviceSchema], default:[],
});
```

Thanks